# get value when updated,outside of formik using useRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, formik, use-ref

I'm trying to get the value of an autocomplete field outside of my formik component everytime it changes, and i did something like this:

```
const formRef=useRef<any>(null);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("eee!!",formRef.current?.values?.flagTR)
},[formRef.current?.values]);
return (
        <Formik
            
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={handleSumbit}
            enableReinitialize={true}
            validateOnChange={true}
            validationSchema={ProduitSchema}
            innerRef={formRef}
        >
```

the useEffect is triggered the first time the component renders,but then when i change the value of the autocomplete the useEffect doesn't get triggered.
what should i do in order to trgger useEffect everytime a value from formik changes?

Comment: could somebody help maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I don't think the approach you are going with here is going to work, it's really not what the useRef hook is for.

The correct approach for what it looks like you want to do is to properly use Formik's context to mapValuesToProps or get access to the values, errors, and validation states.

You can use `withFormik()` to set up your initial form values and mapValuesToProps. Then you can use within the form component formik's `useFormikContext()` which will give you access to values, errors, setValues, etc

```
export default withFormik({
    handleSubmit: () => {},
    validateOnChange: true,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    validateOnMount: true,
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({ name: '', email: '' }),
    initialValues: { name: '', email: '' }
  })(MyFormComponent)
```

In the MyFormComponent you can then call `useFormikContext()` and do whatever you want when the values change.

```
const { setValues, values, isValid, validateForm } = useFormikContext()
```

If for some reason this is not what you want to do, or it does not solve your problem, the only way to achieve what you want in React alone is to useState and and setState each time onChange eg

```
const MyFormComponent = () => {
   const [nameField, nameMeta] = useField(name)    
   const [emailField, emailMeta] = useField(email)
   const [formState, setFormState] = useState({name: '', email: ''})
    

   return (
     <Formik
      enableReinitialize
      validateOnBlur={false}
      initialValues={formState}
      onSubmit={() => {}}
    >
      {props => {
         const onChange = e => {
           const targetEl = e.target
           const fieldName = targetEl.name
              setFormState({
                  ...formState,
                  [fieldName]: targetEl.value
              })
              return props.handleChange(e)
          }
    
         return (
            <>
              <input {...nameField} onChange={onChange}>
              <input {...emailField} onChange={onChange}>
            </>
         )
      </Formik>
)
```